# CSV data analysis with python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I should analyse the data in csv file. I need to visualize and print:

1. Diagram of site traffic (most visited)
2. Number of users, who visit every website
3. Time spent online on the website

How can I do the first(diagram of site traffic) separately to 2014 and 2015 with this data:

```
address            used_at
am.ru              2014         413071
                   2015         183402
auto.ru            2014        9122342
                   2015        6923367
avito.ru           2014       84503151
                   2015       87688571
avtomarket.ru      2014         106849
                   2015          95927
cars.mail.ru/sale  2014         211456
                   2015         167278
drom.ru            2014       11014955
                   2015        9704124
e1.ru              2014       28678357
                   2015       27961857
irr.ru/cars        2014         222193
                   2015         133678
```

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: assuming that the data you have provided is in `df` data frame: `df.plot(kind='barh')`

Answer (score 3):

I have generated sample input data (3 web sites, timespan: 2 years, 100.000 entries) as you didn't provide it.

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('avito_trend.csv', parse_dates=['ts'], usecols=['userid','site','ts','duration'])

print('Time spent online per web site')
print(df.groupby('site').agg({'duration': 'sum'}))

print('Time spent online per web site, per year')
print(df.groupby([df.ts.dt.year, 'site']).agg({'duration': 'sum'}))

# calculating stats
stats = df.groupby([df.ts.dt.year, 'site'], sort=True)['userid'] \
          .count() \
          .reset_index() \
          .rename(columns={'userid':'visits'}) \


stats = stats.set_index(stats.ts.astype(str) + ': ' + stats.site) \
             .drop(['ts','site'], axis=1)

# plot part
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

title = 'site statistics (visitors)'

stats.plot(kind='barh', ax=ax, title=title, color=['grey'], legend=None)

[ax.annotate(str(visits), (stats.values.max()/2, i))
 for i, visits in enumerate(stats['visits'].tolist())]

plt.show()
fig.savefig('stats.png',dpi=100,bbox='Tight')
```

Output:

```
Time spent online per web site
                duration
site
aliexpress.com  16603827
avito.ru        16560223
rozetka.ua      16731197

Time spent online per web site, per year
                     duration
ts   site
2014 aliexpress.com   8242863
     avito.ru         8288967
     rozetka.ua       8392353
2015 aliexpress.com   8360964
     avito.ru         8271256
     rozetka.ua       8338844
```

[image]

PS please always provide sample input (5-10 rows) and expected output (based on sample data)

Comment: If I need to print separately 2014 and 2015 year, what should i do? For example                `address            used_at
am.ru              2014         413071
                   2015         183402
auto.ru            2014        9122342
                   2015        6923367
avito.ru           2014       84503151
                   2015       87688571
avtomarket.ru      2014         106849
                   2015          95927`

Comment: @ldevyataykina, you should update your question with an example of expected output

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to visualize and print the rows in csv then the following code should work.

```
table = []
with open('avito_trend.csv') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    for row in reader:
        table.append(row)
print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include what the csv file your using looks like, can't help if I do not know what I am referencing.

As a tip, you can use pandas read_csv method instead of having to use csv at all.

ex: `infile=pd.read_csv("avito_trend.csv")`

Comment: I use csv file with 498430 strings. They all looks like dc2829da4d79ad3f5549588471f0d534,"avito.ru",2014-11-26 22:35:08,132,7.                                                                                               1 - id of users; 2 - website; 3 - data of visiting; 4 - time online at website, 5 - it's not important

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Your asking some major questions, you should have some code started, or break up the project into more manageable tasks..

Comment: I need to group by year of visit. But i have date in a format 2014-11-26 22:35:08 and I don't know have can I do it